# Android Studio : SQLite Database Query for getting closest location from coordinates

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have a database of campsites with a name, latitude, and longitude column.
I am trying to execute the query using a cursor object but I can't seem to get it working.

I have:

```
 Campsite getClosestCampsite() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT COL_NAME, COL_LATITUDE, COL_LONGITUDE, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Campsite campsite = new Campsite();
    campsite.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    campsite.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(6));
    campsite.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(7));
    cursor.close();
    return campsite;
}
```

So I am just trying to return 1 campsite, AKA the closest campsite so I can pass the name and coordinates to a google maps function.
Am I typing the query correct to get the closest location based off latitude and longitude?

The IDE underlines HAVING and is giving me , , , AS GROUP or semicolon expected

Table structure:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // CREATE TABLE
    String CREATE_CAMPSITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CAMPSITES + "("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COL_CITY + " TEXT," + COL_FEATURE + " TEXT," + COL_FAVORITE + " TEXT," + COL_RATING + " INTEGER," + COL_LATITUDE + " REAL," + COL_LONGITUDE + " REAL" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CAMPSITES_TABLE);
```

Comment: `HAVING` -> `WHERE`

Comment: Also, `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HAVING** requires a **GROUP BY** clause, as per the highlighted part of :-

[image]

[SQL As Understood By SQLite- SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

You want to use **WHERE** instead of having, so :-

```
String query = "SELECT COL_NAME, COL_LATITUDE, COL_LONGITUDE, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES WHERE distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;"
```

You will then get an error CURSOR INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS because after the Cursor is generated it is positioned before the first row (-1). You need to move to a row in the Cursor (if any exist) use something like :-

```
Campsite campsite = new Campsite();
if (cursor.moveToFirst() {
    campsite.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    campsite.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(6));
    campsite.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(7));
}
cursor.close();
return campsite;
```

- Noting that if no rows are selected, then the returned Campsite object will be as per when it is constructed (which you should check for).

Comment: @Shawn oops will fix.

Comment: I am thinking it is better just to get the entire row so I can return the campsite with all the fields. Wouldn't this not work for retrieving the object in my maps activity since I am only setting 3 fields but there are 7 columns. So how could I select all the columns of the closest campsite. I'm thinking I have to use * but I just don't know the syntax since this query is more complex then I am used to.

Comment: String query = "SELECT * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES WHERE distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;"

Like that to get all columns?

Comment: I don't believe you understood. If there are no campsites where the calculated distance is < 25, then the query will return no rows. In that situation `moveToFirst()` will return false (and the cursor is positioned at after the last row). As such none of the values (as there aren't any to use), so the name,latitude and longitude will not be set when the Campsite object is returned. Re 2nd comment, you would need a comma after the first `*`. In short you may need to handle a `no campsites within a distance of 25` situation, and the note was warning of this.

Comment: Oh I missed that. To be clear, I am returning a campsite no matter what because I was going to change the distance to like 3000 miles. All the campsites' coordinates are in california and the location it is testing against is also in california, so it will return the closest location correct?

Comment: As you have LIMIT 1, there's no need for the WHERE clause, the ORDER BY and LIMIT will return the nearest. Then the only situation where there would only be no rows if there were no campsite rows at all.

Comment: So just remove WHERE distance < 25 from the query and I'm all set? Would I need to add a comma after FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES or am I fine just deleting WHERE distance < 25
Thanks for the help.

Comment: String query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;"

Comment: @Etra `String query = "SELECT COL_NAME, COL_LATITUDE, COL_LONGITUDE, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;"` should be fine, as would `String query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1;"`

Comment: I am getting this error when running my app:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_CAMPSITES (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT COL_NAME, COL_LATITUDE, COL_LONGITUDE, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM TABLE_CAMPSITES ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1

Comment: and when I pasted the second String query you posted above, I get ' ; ' expected error at the end, but if I add a ; at the end, I get the no such table found error.

Comment: @Etra String query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM " +  TABLE_CAMPSITES + " ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1"; i.e. you need the resolved value of the TABLE_CAMPSITES variable to be part of the string.

Comment: sorry for this but now I am getting:
no such function: acos (code 1): , while compiling:

Comment: @Etra That's because there are no such functions in SQLite, these are the available functions [Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Comment: So in order for this query to work I would need to create those methods myself correct?

Comment: @Etra to ascertain the distance it's either customise SQLite or do the calculation elsewhere.

Comment: Yea sounds ideal to do it elsewhere. I could get list of all campsites and loop through lat,long columns of each campsite and do the calculation. Now I just gotta figure that out haha. Anyway thanks for the help!